# Looping through and combining calls to Woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I have to make calls to multiple pages of a Woocommerce product database (getting all products in one go seems to not be an option), and the looping and collection of the results isn't working as I expect. I should see an array with just under 900 objects, but all I'm seeing is an empty array. I'm very new to PHP. THe relevant code below:

```
function get_awesome_products() {
  for ($count = 1; $count <= 9; $count++ ) {
  if ($count < 2) { $completeProductList = []; }
   $baseRequest = 'https://myawesomeapi/wp-json/wc/v3/products/? 
 consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxxx&per_page=100&page=';
 $request = wp_remote_get( $baseRequest . (string)$count);
 $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
 $data = array_values(json_decode( $body, true ));

if (count($completeProductList < 1)) {
  $completeProductList = $data;
} else {
$completeProductList = array_merge($completeProductList, $data);
}
}
return new WP_REST_Response($completeProductList, 200);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
register_rest_route('awe/v1', 'aweproducts', array(
'methods' => 'GET',
'callback' => 'get_awesome_products',
'permission_callback' => function () {
  return true;
    }
  ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not clear why *getting all products in one go seems to not be an option* if you have control on the API 
you can add a custom endpoint and write your query to get all the products ( maybe in status "publish")
something like :

```
global $wpdb;
$Q="SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status ='publish'";
$completeProductList = $wpdb->get_results($Q);
return new WP_REST_Response($completeProductList, 200);
```

should work.

Second : without testing your function I think that

`if (count($completeProductList < 1))` should be `if (count($completeProductList) < 1)` 
your code is counting a boolean instead of a *Countable interface*, maybe it's not the final solution but this looks like a bug

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, while I have read access to this API, I don't have control over the API, and Woocommerce's current REST API doesn't have a way to request all of *whatever* in the current version.

Comment: Did you try to change the count() as per second part of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Andrea had at least part of the answer above when he pointed out that I had a variable improperly enclosed above. The other issues at play were:

- Not calling `array_values()` on the array after `json_decode` was called.
- Variable scope issues?

If anybody else runs into a similar issue, here is the code that worked for me:

```
function get_awesome_products() {
$baseRequest = 'https://myawesomeapi/wp-json/wc/v3/products/? 
consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxxx&per_page=100&page=';
 for ($count = 1; $count <= 9; $count++ ) {
$request = wp_remote_get( $baseRequest . (string)$count);
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$data = array_values( json_decode( $body, true ));

if ($count < 2) {
  $completeProductList = $data;
} else {
  $completeProductList = array_merge($completeProductList, $data);
}
}
return new WP_REST_Response($completeProductList, 200);
```